# Unable to group the element value using group by in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an XML lie below:

```
 <Products>
        <Product1>
            <Reference>000510143244</Reference>
            <Value1>543</Value1>
        </Product1>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product1>
            <Reference>000510143244</Reference>
            <Value1>543</Value1>
        </Product1>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product1>
            <Reference>45768799322</Reference>
            <Value1>543</Value1>
        </Product1>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product2>
            <Reference>35726318090</Reference>
            <Value1>543</Value1>
        </Product2>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product2>
            <Reference>35726318090</Reference>
            <Value1>543</Value1>
        </Product2>
    </Products>
```

I want to get only first value of the Product1 reference...but I am unable to get that.Also it is not mandatory that Product 1 will always be the first element in input xml.

Any suggestions how can I get that?

I have tried to get the value as :

```
<xsl:template match="//Products">
  <xsl:variable name="Product1">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/Reference" group-by="/Reference">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

Update:1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Products[child::Product1][1]">

        <xsl:value-of select="." />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output is :000510143244

Comment: Why do you want to use group-by ? And please elaborate your requirements. It's still not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Here,I have similar three Product1 node,I want the value of the first Reference only.

Comment: Also,it is not mandatory that Product1 will always be the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first occurrence of `<Products>` who has `<Product1>`, you might need to match the parent tag or root tag of your input XML.

Assuming your input as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>
    <Products>
        <Product2>
            <Reference>35726318090</Reference>
        </Product2>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product1>
            <Reference>02563899183</Reference>
        </Product1>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product1>
            <Reference>000510143244</Reference>
        </Product1>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product1>
            <Reference>000510143244</Reference>
        </Product1>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <Product2>
            <Reference>35726318090</Reference>
        </Product2>
    </Products>
</root>
```

The following code can give you the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Products/Product1" group-by="Reference">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See the demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zx

**Update:**

OR you can simply achieve it by following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Products[child::Product1][1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update 2:**

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="ref">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Products/Product1" group-by="Reference">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/Reference" />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ref"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zx/1

**Update 3:**

You cannot assign a value to global variable from a template.

There are two ways to get what you required.

**1)** Create a global variable as below which will take first `<Products>` whose child element is `<Product1>` and will display it's `Reference`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="ref" select="root/Products[child::Product1][1]/Product1/Reference" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$ref" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**2)** You can modify the template as below to get the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Products[child::Product1][1]/Product1/Reference">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please look at the updated input xml,with this it displays all the value under Product1....but I need only Reference

Comment: And how do I store the value  in a variable

Comment: This wont work to give the first reference when the value changes in each reference

Comment: What i mean here is ...with this XSL  in the updated Input xml,we will get the result as 02563899183000510143244,but the expected is 02563899183

Comment: Update 1 in the question section is what I have tried...this is giving me unique values but both reference and value are getting displayed,but I want only reference value stored in a global variable

Comment: I have updated it as **update 3**. Please make clear of what you have, what you exactly want. The expected output is different in your question and the comment updated recently.